# Group by time frequency within a date range for every individual row

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a problem that I have not encountered in the past and am not sure how to approach this.

Consider these two tables/rows.

locations table

```
id | name | prices_checked_at
1 | "los angeles" | 2023-02-02 00:00:01
2 | "new york" | 2023-02-02 00:00:01
```

items table

```
id | name | price | location_id | updated_at
1 | "burger" | 2.90 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:01
2 | "burger" | 3.45 | 2 | 2022-11-01 00:00:01
```

What I am trying to do is get an average price of an item with a name "burger", group by month. So right now, we're using just the `updated_at` timestamp.

The issue is that for item id 1 for example, the price of $2.90 is not just valid on `2023-01-01 00:00:01` (or for the month of January) but rather from `2023-01-01 00:00:01` until `2023-02-02 00:00:01` (when the location prices were last checked).

So what is the most efficient way of creating the averages of data while each row is used in multiple months based on the date range?

The expected output would be something like:

```
month | price
2022-11 | 3.45
2022-12 | 3.45
2023-01 | 3.18
2023-02 | 3.18
```

Comment: Postgres or Redshift? Those are two very different databases.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's for Redshift but since Redshift is based on Postgres, many things that work there will work just fine and sometimes better on Redshift. The reason I tagged both is because Redshift gets significantly less attention.

Comment: No, Redshift is not "based" on Postgres. That's something the Amazon marketing is trying to sell. To my knowledge, the only part that is from Postgres is their SQL parser, all the important parts are completely different. It's highly likely that a Postgres query will not work with Redshift.

Comment: Alright... so far all postgres queries worked just fine in Redshift for me...